# Is there a more efficient way to use grep?

Tags: linux, grep

I have been using grep to search databases. I've been using the following command when searching multiple folders with multiple text files.

```
grep 'text_search' */*
```

is there a better command that will speed up the process of searching through large amounts of data? I am open to using other tools if needed.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a fan of [ripgrep](https://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/)

If you prefer to stick with grep, `grep -F` matches strings not patterns (which may or may not be faster; I'm not sure if modern greps simplify a simple pattern to a string search).

Running `grep` in parallel is also an option. I use [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/) for this.

```
find . -type f | parallel --jobs {#jobs} -n 500 -k -m grep -H {search-pattern} {}
```

(jobs and search-pattern aren't surrounded in braces; they indicate a variable you need to enter)

Comment: Theres also ack and ag, off the top of my head, and fzf depending on what youre doing.

Comment: I'd avoid parallelism if you have a rotational hard disk, however fast it may be.  Or at least benchmark it with a cold cache (`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`) before settling on it as a real benefit.  The only time I have benefited from any parallelism is when the data can fit in RAM and I have to make multiple greps, one after another.  In that case, the first one is slow (it reads from disk), but subsequent ones are very fast.